# Is the Baltic Sea considered included in the area covered by the NATO treaty?

Tags: nato, international-waters

Article 6 of the NATO treaty specifically mentions the Mediterranean Sea, but not the Baltic Sea. So do NATO countries consider an attack on their aircraft or vessels in the Baltic Sea, but in international waters thereof, as falling under the area covered by the NATO treaty? (There's always the more vague "North Atlantic area north of the Tropic of Cancer" as the catch-all in the end). I'm guessing this issue of the Baltic Sea might have come up during the treaty drafting or later in some later, post-treaty discussions.

Comment: I can't speak for the drafters but it's pretty obvious looking at a map that the Baltic sea was behind the iron curtain so there weren't NATO members at the time that this would affect.

Comment: @uberhaxed What about Denmark and Germany?

Comment: @convert Germany obviously not (east Germany was not NATO) and the area extending  to what would be Denmark's border would be over the neutral states terrestrial waters.

Comment: @uberhaxed Kiel is not east Germany: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiel_Canal

Comment: @convert nor sure what a canal (over land by definition) has to do with the sea (international or economic zone away from country borders).

Comment: @uberhaxed West Germany had also acces to Baltic See, so there must be german economic zone as well.

Comment: @uberhaxed West Germany was an "area in Europe in which occupation forces of any of the Parties were stationed on the date when the Treaty entered into force."  An attack on NATO forces in West German territorial waters would be covered by article 6, including West Germany's territorial waters in the Baltic sea, even before West Germany joined NATO.

Comment: @uberhaxed: fair point, I think, at the time of drafting. But in the meantime NATO has expanded to include East Germany, Poland, the 3 Baltic countries. The Baltic Sea is very much discussed nowadays in NATO documents, but mostly from the perspective of Russian area denial capabilities from Kaliningrad, as far as I can tell https://www.jstor.org/stable/resrep16803?seq=2

Comment: @convert Yes and an aircraft shot down over the canal or 1 km from the coast would indisputably be over west Germany, not the Baltic sea which was the context of the question.

Comment: @uberhaxed but an aircraft shot down over the sea 1 km from the canal would indisputably be over West German territorial waters and the Baltic Sea.

Comment: @phoog the treaty already covers attacks on territory, the question was about extraterritorial attacks.

Comment: It's  pretty obvious that Baltic sea is part of North Atlantic. At least that what geography lessons in Poland in the 90s and 00s said

Comment: Also 8f you could cite the article 6 that would be helpful

Comment: @PiotrGolacki the Mediterranean is not as far as I know considered to be part of the Atlantic by anyone.  It is covered separately in the treaty.  Why would the Baltic be different?

Comment: @phoog as far as I know the Mediterranean is 3rd largest sea of the Atlantic ocean. Just check the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: @PiotrGolacki "The Mediterranean Sea is a sea connected to the Atlantic Ocean, surrounded by the Mediterranean Basin and almost completely enclosed by land.... Although the Mediterranean is sometimes considered a part of the Atlantic Ocean, it is usually referred to as a separate body of water." But the treaty's internal evidence is more compelling: it mentions the Mediterranean and the Atlantic separately, and it doesn't mention the Baltic.